# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Contract') - Next.js, web3.0

Tags: reactjs, next.js, provider, web3js

I'm trying to create a small web3.0 app, using next.js.
I have deployed my contract on rinkeby test network, and I am able to check the functionalities using Remix, work properly. I have also worked on similar projects on react, they also work as exepected.
But when I try to connect I am currently facing the following issue (maybe this has something to do with Server side rendering of next.js or HttpProvider, I'm not sure):

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Contract')
  3 | import address from './build/campaignHubAddress.json';
  4 | 
> 5 | const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, address.campaignHubAddress);
    |                     ^
  6 | export default instance;
```

web3.js

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
let web3;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
    window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
} else {
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/3ed112ee6c4d42a09e485ddb5eec5fa2'
    );
    web3 = new Web3(provider);
}
export default web3;
```

instance.js

```
import web3 from 'web3';
import contract from './build/CampaignHub.json';
import address from './build/campaignHubAddress.json';

const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, address.campaignHubAddress);
export default instance;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import web3 from '../web3';
import instance from '../instance';

class Index extends React.Component{
    static async getInitialProps(){
        const campaigns = await instance.methods.getCampaigns().call();
        return { campaigns };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <p>Hello, this is the test page for now.</p>
                <p>Web3 version: {web3.version}</p>
                <p>List of all the running campaigns: {this.props.campaigns} </p>
            </>
        );
    }
}
export default Index;
```

This seems basic, but I have been stuck at it for some time now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After scratching a lot of head, I found that the error was in `instance.js`. While importing `import web3 from 'web3';` I should have done `import web3 from './web3';`

Answer (score 0):

You already create instance of your web3 in web3.js
you can use it directly without using the "new"

```js
import web3 from 'web3';
import contract from './build/CampaignHub.json';
import address from './build/campaignHubAddress.json';

const instance = web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, address.campaignHubAddress);
export default instance;
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.